# How to write proper rspec test for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uitableview, rspec

I have controller called Application controller with next method for which I want to write test for:

```
  def require_admin
    p current_user.role
    return if current_user && current_user.role == 'admin'
    flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

How to write proper test for it, and what kind of test should it be?

Comment: expect(response).to redirect_to()

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't test implementation. Try testing 'how should this controller action behave for a non-admin user', it might look like this:

```
context 'user who is not an admin' do
  before do
    user.role = 'not_admin'
    get :some_action
  end

  it 'is redirected to root_path' do        
    expect(response).to redirect_to('/')
  end
  ...
end
```